# Allow user to upload picture in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, image, upload, save

I am very new to Visual Basic so please be gentle. :P

I am creating a small application, for basic learning purposes, which will allow a user of the application to update a profile of sorts. This includes, uploading a profile picture, which is then stored in /bin/Debug/Resource and then displayed on their profile in a PictureBox.

I am using the following code, which seems to do just that. However, when I close the application and run it again, the image is not displayed on either PictureBox but is still stored in the designated folder.

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("Resource")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Resource")
    End If


    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    With OpenFileDialog1
        .CheckFileExists = True
        .ShowReadOnly = False
        .Filter = "All Files|*.*|Bitmap Files (*)|*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg"
        .FilterIndex = 2

        '
        If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim FName() As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Split("\\")
            System.IO.File.Copy(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, "Resource\\" + FName(FName.Length - 1))
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(.FileName)
            Profile.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(.FileName)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help that you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use LoadPicture to load the picture into the box.
imgMyPic.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\SomeDirectory\SomeSubDir\MyPic.bmp")

Comment: I have tried:

    imgMyPic.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\SomeDirectory\SomeSubDir\MyPic.bmp")

But it shows the following errors:

Picture is not a member of System.Windows.Form.PictureBox'

LoadPicture is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level'

Comment: The image isn't stored (or reloaded) automatically so you'll have to reload the image (from file) again on form load.

Comment: That should be `.Image` not `.Picture` liek this `imgMyPic.Image = LoadPicture("C:\SomeDirectory\SomeSubDir\MyPic.bmp")`

Comment: @MattWilko this was earlier tagged as VBA and not VB .NET

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do in order to display the picture.

This code will have to be added to the Load form method.

```
Dim StoredPath As String = "PathToImage"
IF File.Exists(StoredPath) Then
   PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@StoredPath)
   PictureBox1.Refresh()
End if
```

Comment: What are you getting in the OpenFileDialog1.FileName? I have created a [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: I'm not getting anything different. Displays the image but when I close the application and open it again, the image is gone.

Comment: @user3271273 The application will not store the image in the picture box. Once you've exit the application, the image is gone. The way to change that behavior is to have a startup routine that will assign the image to the picture box and refresh it.

Comment: Yes I understand that. What I have so far is the image being uploaded to /bin/Debug/Resource. So what I am trying to do is each time the application loads, the last displayed image is shown.